# Custom react hook can not be called in useEffect with empty dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im new to react hook, Im doing a project with new feature "Hooks" of react.

I've faced a problem and I need an explain for it.

As document, to implement "componentDidMount", just pass empty array in dependencies argument.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // some code here
  }, []);
```

And I can call dispatch function to updateState inside this useEffect.

```
const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setFlag(true);
}, []);
```

Above code works perfectly without warning or any errors.

Now I have my custom hook, but I can not call my dispatch inside the effect.

```
const [customFlag, setCustomFlag] = useCustomHook();

useEffect(() => {
  setCustomFlag(true);
}, []);
```

This is my custom hook.

```
function useCustomHook() {
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false):

  const component = <div>{ success ? "Success" : "Fail" }</div>;
  const dispatch = useCallback(success => {
    setSuccess(success);
  }, []);

  return [component, dispatch]; 
}
```

With above code, it requires me to put setCustomFlag inside the dependencies array.

I do not understand why. What is different between them?

Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Idan I updated my customHook

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue passing setSuccess and setCustomFlag as deps since the references these are pointing at shouldn't change

Comment: Probably not the catch, still are you using the latest version of react/dom?

Comment: You can try wrapping your logic in a function and pass the function as a parameter

For example:

const effectFn = () => {
  setCustomFlag(true);
};
useEffect(effectFn, []);



This should take care of the warning

Comment: Why do you think your code doesn't work? I've took your component and tried to render it - everything is fine ( https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-dawn-b6w8y ). It was rendered with `Fail` message, and then after a moment rendered with `Success` message 2nd time. Do you expect another behaviour?

Comment: @Andres I have used eslint-plugin-react-hooks, and it warning missing dependencies.

That's why Im not sure any thing wrong with my code.

Comment: @user3079975 this warning means you need to add dependencies to `useEffect()` and `useCallback()` calls. In case of `useEffect()` since you want your code to be invoked only once just ignore this warning or add `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` to your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, your custom hook returns different instance of `setCustomFlag` on each call. It means, that `useEffect()` will always use first value (returned on first render). Try to memoize it by calling `useCallback()`/`useMemo()` hooks:

```js
function useCustomHook() {
  ...

  const setCustomFlag = useCallback(/* setCustomFlag body here */, []);
}
```

It would be nice to have your custom hook source to say more.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question.

I tried using useCallback, but it still is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is setFlag from useState is a known dependency, its value won't change between render, hence you don't have to declare it as a dependency

React eslint-plugin-react-hooks can't be sure about your custom hook, that's why you need to put that into the dependency list

This is taken from [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9e64bf18e11828d6b4c0363bff5ed2eca1ccd838/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/ExhaustiveDeps.js)

```
      // Next we'll define a few helpers that helps us
      // tell if some values don't have to be declared as deps.

      // Some are known to be static based on Hook calls.
      // const [state, setState] = useState() / React.useState()
      //               ^^^ true for this reference
      // const [state, dispatch] = useReducer() / React.useReducer()
      //               ^^^ true for this reference
      // const ref = useRef()
      //       ^^^ true for this reference
      // False for everything else.
      function isStaticKnownHookValue(resolved) {
      }
```